# Netbeans,SQL query after connection

Tags: sql, netbeans

After successful connection with sql server (using wamp), ive added a simple table with 1 column and one value, so im trying to take that value and update the jlist. It shows no error and it doesnt work,forgive me if im done someting stupid. (Also im writing this inside a jcombobox event handler)

```
 private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

        String a = null;
        String que="SELECT * FROM game";
        Connection dn=null;
        Statement st=null;
        ResultSet sm=null;
        String db="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project";
        try{

            dn=DriverManager.getConnection(db, "user", "");
            st=dn.prepareStatement(que);
            sm=st.executeQuery(que);
            while(sm.next())
            {
                a=sm.getString(1);
            }

        DefaultListModel n=new DefaultListModel();
        n.addElement(a);
        jList1.setModel(n);
        }
      catch(SQLException e)
              {

              }
    }
```

Comment: You should use `getString("columnName")` but maybe `getString(0)` will work.

Comment: But the column index starts from 1, is there any way to confirm the data is being accused by the code though?